Error in Symfony with Overblog: Could not find type with alias "Query"
I have using symfony with overblog/graphql-bundle.
While creating simple project with sample query and resolver,
Got an error "Could not find type with alias "Query". Did you forget to define it?"
# config/packages/overblog_graphql.yaml
overblog_graphql:
    definitions:
        schema:
            query: Query
        mappings:
            auto_discover:
                bundles: true
            types:
                yaml:
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/Graphql/types'
    errors_handler:
        enabled: true

# config/graphql/type/Query.types.yaml
Query:
  type: object
  config:
    fields:
      user:
        type: String
        resolve: "@=query('App\\Resolver\\UserQueryResolver')"

# config/routes/graphql.yaml
overblog_graphql_endpoint:
  path: /graphql
  controller: Overblog\GraphQLBundle\Controller\GraphController::endpointAction
  methods: [POST]

overblog_graphql_batch:
  path: /graphql/batch
  controller: Overblog\GraphQLBundle\Controller\GraphController::batchEndpointAction
  methods: [POST]

# App/Resolver/UserQueryResolver
<?php

namespace App\Resolver;

class UserQueryResolver
{
    public function __invoke($value, $args, $context, $info)
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}

Here I have used PHP 8.2 and Symfony 7.1. How can I generate schema without this Issue.
